# How to use a button to add 4 slider values together?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uilabel, uislider

I've attempted this multiple times, 1st by just trying to add the labels under my sliders (see picture below), but labels do not support integers. My newest attempt used 4 integer variables and set the label value to it, the only thing wrong with this method is it only works with one label, if I do this for all 4 I cannot add them together.  `

```
var aValue: Int {
  didSet {
     mathCriAValue.text = "\(aValue)"
  }
}

@IBAction func mathCriAChanged( sender: UISlider) {
   aValue = Int(sender.value)
}
```

[Main storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6nFy.png)

Comment: What about using tags to differentiate them. Set `aValue`, `bValue` etc, and in each of them the `didSet{}` change the label, and do the recalculation for the last one (sum) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a reference to each of your sliders and each of your labels (i.e. make them all IBOutlet properties).
2. When your slider event is triggered, check which slider is the sender and update the text in the appropriate label:

`labelA.text = "\(sliderA.value)"`

3. Sum up the values of all sliders:

`let total = sliderA.value + sliderB.value + sliderC.value + sliderD.value`

4. Set the text in the total label (to which you also need a reference):

`totalLabel.text = "\(total)"`

Comment: If I already have code in place for having the original 4 labels to display their respective slider values, what is another way to do this? (Code): let currentValue = Int(sender.value)
        
        MathCriAValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
Can I keep my old code for the slider-> label values while still using this code?
I also got this warning while trying to add my "total" variable: "Initialization of variable 'total' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it"

Comment: Sorry My last comment about the warning/error was incorrect, I had my "total" variable as a "var" and not a "let" I have a new error; Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions." I have gotten this error while adding all of the values together before how do I solve it?

Comment: So do you have four functions named mathCriAChanged, mathCriBChanged, etc? Or how do you differentiate between the four sliders? Then your total is just aValue + bValue + cValue + dValue. And you could update your total in your IBActions.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?